# Replace a string in many files at once using Visual Studio build event

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, command-line, batch-file, command-prompt

I need a pre-build event command that will iterate through a group of files of a certain type recursively within a directory hierarchy and replace a string with another string.

How I'd envision using the command would be something like:

```
replace [ROOTPATH] [FILETYPE] [TARGETSTRING] [REPLACEMENTSTRING]
```

So if I was to put this command in my pre-build events:

```
replace "$(ProjectDir)Views" "*.cs" "~/Views" "~/Areas/Admin/Views"
```

every file with the .cs extension under the views folder would be altered to replace "~/Views" with "~/Areas/Admin/Views". Note that I want the file altered and not to pipe the results out into a new file.

[I know unix has a command called replace](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-replace-text-string-in-many-files-at-once.html) that does what I'm looking for if I was to build it into a script.

Is there a command available in dos to do this already or alternatively a script that has been built that could do this function for me?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I think this batch is hard to find, so I thought I would post it here. you can enhance this batch by yourselfe adding parameters [ROOTPATH] and [FILETYPE] or somethig and enhance this batch to only do the string changes on your files.

My post got deleted cause this is not the direct answer to your question but I think it helps you realy good to reach your goal.

The answer to your question is: no such a command is not existing you have to create your own batch file (like my linked one) to reach the goal.

For more information, have a look at the following link, this should help you by replacing strings inside a file via DOS:
http://www.dostips.com/?t=batch.findandreplace

Comment: Iam sorry for confusing every moderator here in this thread.
I couldnt "undelete" my comment so I decided to repost the edited answer.
My first answer which was deleted was only containing the link and 1 sentence this was to less. As I was not able to undelete the answer I decided to flag it that some moderator can have a look at this. Iam sorry again for confusing everyone. I now know how to act. As I have not enough time to develop "the perfect" solution I decided to post a very helpful link (in my eyes) to help you a lil bit instead of not helping. I will not do this again.